# What does nonlinear mapping $\Phi(x)$ mean? Is it a vector or matrix?

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I'm reading a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alejandro-Frangi/publication/27411101_KPCA_Plus_LDA_A_complete_Kernel_Fisher_Discriminant_Framework_for_Feature_Extraction_and_Recognition/links/61c20772c99c4b37eb12cd01/KPCA-Plus-LDA-A-complete-Kernel-Fisher-Discriminant-Framework-for-Feature-Extraction-and-Recognition.pdf) about image classification. According to the paper, it says

For a given nonlinear mapping $\Phi (x)$, the input data space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be
mapped into the feature space $\cal H$:

$$\Phi : \mathbb{R}^{n} \mapsto \cal H$$

$$x \mapsto \Phi(x)$$

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

What does this mean?
Is $x_i$ a vector or a matrix? Can somewone give an example how $\Phi$ might look like?

Comment: $x_i$ will just be some element of $\Bbb R^n$ ("a vector")

Comment: $\Phi(x)$ may also be vector-valued, or even function-valued. For example, $\Phi(x) = (x_1,x_2,x_1^2 + x_2^2)$ or $\Phi(x) = \sin(x_1t)\cdot\sin(x_2t)$

Comment: @FShrike and the $\Phi$ ? I assume it's a kernel, but I have never seen application onto a vector with s kernel, matrix only.

Comment: @whpowell96 so $\Phi(x)$ is just a arbitrary function with arguments $x$?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on the Hilbert space structure of $\mathcal{H}$

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “kernel” here. $\Phi$ is just some function (which fails to be linear). No other information is provided at this stage

Answer (score 0):

In the formula you are asking about $x_i$ is the i-th coordinate vector of the input space (which is $\mathbb{R}^n$). The $y_j$ should probably be $x_j$, that's a typo.

The feature map is an arbitrary map into the feature space $H$. For example, if $H$ is finite dimensional (say, of dimension $m$), you can pick an orthonormal basis for it, and think of each component of $\Phi$ in that basis as a feature. This is what scalar features are. In this case you have complete freedom to choose $m$ arbitrary scalar valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as your scalar features (i.e. the components of your feature map). One option is to take as features  all the monomials of degree at most $d$ in original coordinates, scaled in some way. For a particular choice of scalings, this is equivalent to using the [polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel). In practice, one often starts with a kernel, and leaves $\Phi$ and $H$ implicit; in most cases the corresponding $H$ is infinite-dimensional, and the corresponding $\Phi$ is non-linear (and mapping into the infinite-dimensional $H$).

Comment: Can you give me some example, like code or something?

Comment: An example of what? Of an arbitrary map? Or? In code of what kind? It's very rare to code a feature function, you code with the kernel.  The paper you cite says "Two popular kernels are involved in our tests. One is the polynomial kernel  and the other is the Gaussian RBF kernel". I linked you the feature map for the polynomial kernel, click the link and read the formulas. RBF has infinite-dimensional feature map, whose formula you can find in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is because $x$ has the dimension $n$ and with $\Phi(x)$, then it will have the dimension $m$ instead. No kernel will reduce the dimension from $n$ to $m$. If we see equation `(7)` in the paper, $\Phi(x)$ must have the same dimension as $P^T$. But $x$ has the dimension $n$ and $P$ has the dimension $m$.  So how can $\Phi$ reduce the dimension $n$ to $m$ in that case?

Comment: The m in my answer has nothing to do with m in the paper. There it's just some arbitrary truncation parameter. Notation in equation 7 is funky, but dimension of P is definitely not m, it's "m times dimension of H". In 7 one dots each beta_j with Phi(x) to get a scalar y_j, so that y is of dimension m. Anyway, if you have questions about that you should probably ask a separate question.

Comment: No it's not "m times dimension of H". It's dimension $m$.

Comment: I started a new question about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748263/should-gram-matrix-be-r-qtq-or-r-qqt

Comment: Each beta_j is a vector in H. There are m of them. The total dimension is m times dimension of H. Also, M is not the same as m.

Comment: So $m$ is a user selectable number?

Comment: So that means $m$ is smaller than $M$ and that leas to the question in this topic if $\Phi(x)$ maps $n$ dimension vector $x$ to a $m$ dimension vector? Well, in that case, $n$ must be larger than $m$, right?